# Pulling bad chars from an xml feed

Tags: coldfusion

I need to figure out a way to remove any non standard ASCII char from a feed I am getting form a partners system.

The issue is they are sending a mix of data - HTML formatted and hard returns along with bad chars.

I am already using the UDF DeMoronize(text) to pull any Microsoft Latin-1 "Extentions" chars out.

The feed is coming over in utf-8 and we have a tag  on the page to insure we are processing the feed in utf-8.

is there a simple way to code this to remove any NON UTF-8 char?

Comment: _"remove any non standard ASCII char"_ is not the same as _"remove any NON UTF-8 char"_ - what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes I want to remove any NON UTF-8 Chars

Comment: [***what are you actually trying to achieve?***](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) Not what do you _think_ you need to do to solve it, what is the [real problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) that makes you believe the answer is to "remove any NON UTF-8 Chars" (when the actual issue is perhaps more likely to be along the lines of "I need to fix the encoding so I don't get Ás or ?s") - i.e. supply some sample data, your code, and the error that occurs.